# Fetching data from the same server. What url to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react website hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet. I also have a node.js server running on the same droplet. What url should I replace with when fetching from the back end?

The website fetches data correctly when running my front end and back end locally from my computer. When working locally, I used the url http://localhost:3000/users when fetching the data. I tried so many different urls and all of them didn't work when trying it out on the server. This is just one example, I also have other parts in my website where I fetch from but I want to get this part to work first. My example aren't affected by them.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    // for usernames
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ users: data });
}
```

I did https://www.mywebsite.com:3000/users, which gives me the error on the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource at https://www.mywebsite.com/users.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

and

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

on firefox. I tried numerous variations like changing to http, removing www, only putting /users, removing :3000, and much more, and they all didn't work.
If I do curl mywebsite.com:3000/users on the terminal, I get the data I want. It also works if I type that on the browser. Replacing the domain with the ip address works too. So, I did fetch(mywebsite.com:3000/users), and the rest of the code. That doesn't work because fetch wants me to start with http or https.

Edit: I forgot to say that I'm using express.js on the node.js server

Edit: I'm also running the website through nginx. I used this method: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04 to run my back end.

Edit: I found out the back end is running on nginx with the link http://mywebsite.com:3000/users. I get the data when typing that through the browser or terminal again. But my first error changed to:

> Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mywebsite.com:3000/users”
>   www.fakeconomy.com:1:882

That link redirects to mywebsite.com:3000/users and shows the data. So I don't think it's any different from just typing mywebsite.com:3000/users. Changing it to https or adding www. doesn't work.

Comment: it seems cors are disable on server. if you are using expressJs then go to 
https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html
if any other framework for server let me know

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra I followed the link and copy and pasted the app.use() code and added the "next" parameter since I only had (req, res) before. I still get the same error. Do I need to replace anything?

Comment: You making GET request. are you able to get require output by going directly to https://www.mywebsite.com:3000/users from browser?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra Yes. I said that in my question as well. It still works. I tried changing the fetch url back to what you said and it just gives the second error. But I think that was the same before I added the new code.

Comment: Try using cors plugin https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra I already had that in the original code. I removed them to add the app.use() code. Will try again. Edit: The only thing I did for it was doing app.use(cors());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it! I had my nginx proxy server setup wrong. I had it like

```
server {
...

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /users {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

...
}
```

because I didn't know what to put after location / and nginx complained with same locations so I put the server name which was just server (running through pm2). When I typed in mywebsite.com:3000/users, it didn't go through the reverse proxy, because "server" wasn't hit. The problem was the url for fetch just like I thought, but the nginx setting was what caused the confusion. If I had done https://www.mywebsite.com/server for the fetch url, it would have been fine. I was able to solve it when I changed nginx code to location /users and tested with:

```
fetch('https://www.mywebsite.com/users');
```

Answer (score 0):

- You must enable `cors` at Back-end .
- If you want to use `https` you must install ssl for your vps. The best solution is **Let’s Encrypt**

Comment: I think you should use `axios` for fetch data. Try it and show your problem

Answer (score 0):

For sure You should use the same name - please replace localhost with Your webpage DNS name.

FYI:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS